# How to rename the interface name in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: networking

I had to do a emergency upgrade from 18 to 20.04 but one problem I have is that my interface got renamed from eno1 to something else.

I know you can use netplan match to change the name but I can't use this because A) I got a standard image used for many systems so inputting a mac address manually each time won't work and B) I got a bridge that relies on the above interface and it doesn't appear that works in combination with renaming interfaces.

I also tried the ip link set name command but this doesn't survive a reboot.

Is there a sane manner in which I can simply tell Ubuntu to give a set name to a Ethernet device?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18 is a different system (releases that are *year* in format are *snap* only) to a 20.04 system, so are you sure you upgraded from Ubuntu Core 18 to 20.04; ie. change of products.  Ubuntu has had *year* products since 2016.   An upgrade from Ubuntu Core 18 to Ubuntu Core 20 makes no changes to applications (*snap* packages are the same for any release so no changes should have occurred in any 18 to 20 upgrade; again different products to 18.04 & 20.04 or *year.month* systems)

Comment: Sorry, I mean Ubuntu 18.04. Still testing but I think I "solved" the problem by running a cronjob that renames the interface at boot.

Comment: How did you set the interface name in old system? Upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04. What is the target now? This is a big difference, since 18.04 first introduced netplan.